# Fitting of continuous transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, gain, phase, network, frequency-response

I measure a network's transfer function using a network analyzer and therefore have a set of complex data points, representing the network's gain and phase. I wish to fit a continuous, rational transfer function to my measured data to create a model of my network.
To find a discrete-time model, there is the "Frequency Domain Least Squares" algorithm:

http://robotics.itee.uq.edu.au/~elec3004/2014/lectures/Precise%20Filter%20Design%20(chapter).pdf

Several months ago, I found a PDF which presented a very similar method to estimate a continuous transfer function, but I don't remember where it is nor do I remember its name. I only remember that it was also a simple least squares algorithm as in the above link. Does someone have a hint for this?

Update:
Meanwhile I was able to recover the paper I mentioned. It is called 'Practical Transfer Function Estimation and its Application to Wide Frequency Range Representation of Transformers'. In my application, I am not dealing with a transformer but with some other passive electrical network involving RLC components, and I try to fit a transfer function to that. The network analyzer gives me some complex data for logarithmically spaced frequencies. I tried to use the method presented in the paper, but since my frequencies range from several Hz to several 100 MHz, the algorithm is unable to converge because the matrix A involves \$\omega\$, \$\omega^2\$, \$\omega^3\$ and so on - which leads to an ill-conditioned equation system, and therefore it cannot be solved. I wonder whether there are better algorithms than this, or whether this algorithm could be used, though, perhaps with some pre-processing of my frequency data.

Link to the paper I mentioned:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/252689

Comment: Have you tried normalizing the frequency?

Answer (score 1):

You'll be jumping down the rabbit hole of system identification and modelling. Generally speaking you will need two things:

The first is a so-called **estimator** ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator)), that you can use to find the best "fit" of a general rational transfer function. The ones I've encountered most are

- Least-Squares Estimator
- Maximum-Likelihood Estimator ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation))

They work by defining a *cost function* that you try to minimize using the unknown tranfer function coefficients. For the least-squares estimator, the cost function is simply the sum of the squared errors.

The second one is a **model selection criterion** ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection)). In order to avoid modelling the noise of your data points, you can use this criterion to formally find the optimal model complexity (order of the system).

Comment: yes, I know we are talking about system identification here - and since I have already dealt a bit with this topic I know it is quite a rabbit hole :-) meanwhile I found the paper I was talking about - question updated.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of Matlab function `invfreqs` is to identify continuous-time filter parameters from frequency response data. The idea is based on *Levi, E. C. “Complex-Curve Fitting.” IRE Trans. on Automatic Control. Vol. AC-4, 1959, pp. 37–44*. The main problem is to 
adjust n and m parameters (the orders from numerator and denominator).